# How to create snapshot without shutting down instance with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, snapshot

I'm trying to create aws snapshots using boto3.  The idea is to create snapshots so we can recover a corrupted instance volume.  For now, it would be faster than re-launching, re-puppeting, and re-configuring.

I'm trying to automate this with boto3 but the script always shuts down the instance.  This won't do in our production environment.

When I manually create a snapshot in the AWS web console, it does not shut down the instance.

This is my very basic code for creating snapshots for all my instances (filtered):

```
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
for instance in instances:
    blockCount = 0
    for blockDevice in instance.block_device_mappings:
        newSnapName = thisName + "_" + snapshotTag + "_" + timestr + "_" + str(blockCount)
        thisNewSnapshot = ec2.create_snapshot(VolumeId=blockDevice.get('Ebs').get('VolumeId'),Description="Created by create_track_snaps.py from Instance: " + instance.id)
        blockCount += 1
```

It shuts down all the instances involved.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to create a snapshot while the instance is running.  I see a reference to an AWS CLI option, --no-reboot, but I see nothing in the boto3 API to access it.
2. Is it even reasonable to expect a meaningful snapshot if the instance is running during the creation of a snapshot?  I see so many warnings that one should always shut down instances to create a clean snapshot.  Again, this doesn't seem reasonable in a production environment.

Thanks for any tips,
Chris.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be mixing two concepts: Creating an AMI and creating an EBS Snapshot.

When creating an **AMI** (which includes snapshots of all attached volumes), the instance is restarted unless a *no reboot* option is selected.

When creating an **EBS snapshot**, the instance is not impacted.

The code sample you provided takes an EBS Snapshot. That is why the *no reboot* option is not present (it only applies to AMIs).

As per [CreateSnapshot documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateSnapshot.html):

> You can take a snapshot of an attached volume that is in use. However, snapshots only capture data that has been written to your EBS volume at the time the snapshot command is issued; this may exclude any data that has been cached by any applications or the operating system.

Think of it like pulling the power out of a computer — the data might not be saved correctly, but systems can normally recover. This could be sufficient for a backup that is rarely, if ever, used.

Comment: *"Think of it like pulling the power out of a computer."*  This is a correct analogy to what's contained in the created snapshot, but it leaves room for potential confusion... I'm sure you agree, the code shown in the question should not actually be shutting anything down.  Taking snapshots like this should have no meaningful impact on the running instances at all.